# A the function that triggers always when displaying a component in an ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

What would be the function that triggers always when displaying a component in an ionic2 app.

E.g As I noticed `constructor` function in a component triggers only when the component is initialize for the first time or when you do a `push` from a different page.

But constructor will not trigger when clicking the `back` button or switch between `tabs`

Is there any method that will call every time when the component is displayed on the screen ?

## Update

After doing some research (big word for googling ;)) I realize that each tab is keeping its own history stack. E.g If I have two tabs `home` and `search` what ever push, pop I do in the `search` table is independent from the `home tab`

So what I want to do is

- Do a search in `search tab`
- Click search button (`search tab`)
- Should redirect to `home tab` (without loading the search results in the `search tab` itself)

I hope that makes my requirement bit clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ionViewDidEnter` event on the result tab page. That method gets executed everytime the page is entered, so within that method, you could get the result from a previous query back from the service.

Please take a look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y5yQ8a?p=preview)

In the `page2.html` file, (which would be your home tab) I've included this:

```
  ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.result = this.tabService.result;
  }
```

So everytime the user enters in that page, we could get the result from the service again (if the user didn't fill out the query fields in the previous tab, the results from the previous query will be used).

Comment: hi @sebaferreras, that did the trick , thanks a lot. However I noticed it will not work if the you use it in a component (in the page). Directly on the page it works. (I'm happy with that). Thanks for the plunker too. cheers, Sam

Comment: Glad I could help Sam :) In which scenario it won't work? If you want we can find a way to make it work for that case too.

Comment: It seems like it will not work when `ionViewDidEnter` is in a component. As an example , in your plunker if you call `ionViewDidEnter` from an component inside `page2.ts` instead directly from `page2.ts`, thanks :)

Comment: I think in that case we can use an `@Output() childViewDidEnter = new EventEmitter();` in the child component. So when the `ionViewDidEnter()` method is executed in the child component we can do something like `this.childViewDidEnter.emit(true);` and bind that to a method from `page2.ts` that get the results again like this  `<child-component (ionViewDidEnter)="getResults($event)"></child-component>` and in `page2.ts` add that method: `public getResults(){ this.result = this.tabService.result; }`

Answer (score 1):

I believe `ngOnInit()` is what you're looking for. Anything that you put inside of that function will be called every time that the page is initialized (and only after receiving its data-bound properties).

Further reading: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnInit-class.html

Hope that was what you were looking for :)

Comment: Hey @kevin, thanks for the answer, but it seems like `ngOnInit()` does  not triggers when switching between tabs ;(

Comment: What is your use case for reloading the page between tabs? If data is changing from one tab to another, my thought would be that Angular 2 enables it to auto-update, removing the need for reloading the page. A potential alternative is calling router.navigate['/your-url'] any time you click on a tab.

Comment: hey @kevin, my workflow is, I have a search tab and a list tab. When a user selects a search criteria (from search tab) and click search, I save the search query in a service and redirect to the list tab. List tab will read the search query and show the results. (this works fine). but when I switch the tabs (without clicking search), I should have a way to trigger a method to read any previous search queries. Hope I didnt confuse you :). let me know if u need any more info, thanks again

Comment: I believe the only way to make that happen is if you put a `(click) = reloadTabInfo()` in the HTML. That way, through that method call, you can guarantee that you're reloading the page.